# Criando etiquetas para impressora Zebra

Tags: java, android, impressão, impressora

Preciso criar minha própria etiqueta para imprimir na impressora zebra, se alguém tem algum experiencia com a mesma,gostaria de saber como foi feito..

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Melhor explicando:

Tenho uma aplicação em android, consegui fazer a comunicação, funcionando perfeitamente, porem quero enviar meus dados de uma maneira formatada (como geramos um pdf no Ireports....), com a logo da minha aplicação,as Label e minhas variáveis

Comment: Obrigado...porem o link que você mandou não me ajudou =/

Comment: Você consegue fazer esse documento formatado através de alguma ferramenta? Para depois então fazê-lo através de código...

Comment: A comunicação (através do Android) é direta com a impressora ou tem um PC? Caso seja direta, que ferramenta utiliza?

Comment: Consegui! através  de comandos da propria linguagem da impressora, consegui criar etiquetas